# Excel VBA - Next Row error on Activated Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel 2013 workbook.

I was utilising this [SO Answer for Copy and find next blank Row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341195/461887)

My code is

```
Sub Save()
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Set CopyZone = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AO289")
    Set ToDataSheet = Worksheets("_data")
    Set NextRow = Range("B" & ToDataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    CopyZone.Cut
    ToDataSheet.Activate
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set NextRow = Nothing
End Sub
```

Copyzone is the output from my first sheet which has the newly formatted data. I set DataSheet to my to data sheet ("_data"), however it goes into debug on the line.

```
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
```

How do I get it to complete a paste the cut data into the to sheet on the next blank line?

Comment: What error is the vbe showing?

Comment: None just stops and highlights that line no error. I have found that it is specific to the cut function as using copy works.

Comment: From your code I infer that the active sheet at the start of your sub isn't "_data", if so when you set NextRow it won't be on "_data" since you don't specify the worksheet. It should be `Set NextRow = ToDataSheet.Range("B" & ToDataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the below code solves your problem

```
Sub Save()
    Set CopyZone = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AO289")
    Set ToDataSheet = Worksheets("_data")
    CopyZone.Cut Destination:=ToDataSheet.Range("B" & ToDataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfectly simple and sweet.

Comment: Thanks sayth for your comments.